# Can I check dynamically what are the instances of server is running?

Tags: web-server, websphere, application-server

Currently i am using IBM websphere, my ques is, is their any way through which i can find dynamically, what are the instances of server that are running through console or through java API's.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand truly, You can use `serverStatus.sh -all` command in the **bin** directory to get all server status, running or not. Also if you look at the **profiles** directory, in the best practice, you can find the all instances.